# a restful api only uses clean urls - no url variables or post variables

Tags: rest, restful-url

A restful api has to use either get, post, put or delete request methods.  The behavaiour and  data submitted is entirely determined by the uri string. No query paramters or post variables.

Is this true ?

Valid : `http://example.com/foo/84`

**Not** valid : `http://example.com/foo/?value=84`

Valid :

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "http://example.com/foo/84",
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

**Not** valid :

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "http://example.com/foo/",
  data: 84,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

*edit*
Two answers so far, and the contradict each other.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Saying that `http://example.com/foo/?value=84` is not valid is not entireley true. What i mean is that as long that it is a valid URL it will work and you'll be able to get the parameters via get or post.

On the other hand, REST is an architecture and one of its demands is a clean URL (one that does not include params with a '?') so such a url is not considered a REST like URL.

So if you intend to build a REST based application, you should only use clean urls.

**EDIT:**

I see from the comments below you have a problem understanding what is REST so i'll try to give a simple example:

1. In order to get data you will probably use `http://example.com/foo/84` as a get request and the rest FW knows to get resource foo with id 84.
2. In order to post data about foo, you might call: `http://example.com/foo/84` as a POST request and now the Rest FW know that since its a post request it will call the method responsible for handling post and not the one for handling get
3. To delete, you call the same URL with DELETE action and i think you know the rest.

So, although you have the same URL it really matters if its a GET/POST/PUT/DELETE request.

Comment: I don't think our answers disagree although they are formulated differently. For a web API to be considered RESTful it needs to follow a certain pattern. `/foo/?value=84` will work, that's true, but it just won't be a REST API. You will miss certain advantages of REST APIs, in particular caching, if you access resources that way.

Comment: @Laurent the second example in yr answer uses query paramters in the url. It is not clean, but you say it is restful. Whereas this answer says restful must not use url parameters in a get request.

Comment: @NimChimpsky, you need to look at it with and without the query parameters: whether you get `/user/84?fields=first_name,last_name` or `/user/84`, you will get the same user, although with different fields. However, if you compare `/user/?id=84` and `/user/` - in one case you'll get a user, in the second case you will get nothing, there's a lack of consistency. Basically, if adding or changing query parameters return different resources, it means there's a problem in the API.

Comment: @Laurent if you specify first_name you are getting back different data than if you specify last_name. That seems to contradict what you are saying.  Surely the displaying of relevent fields would by handled by the view, not the controller (server) and thus query params should not be used ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky, no, whether you query last_name or first_name, you are still getting the same resource. In theory the view should indeed handle displaying the relevant fields and no query parameters would be necessary. In practice, you will need query parameters so that you don't transfer entire resources every time. This is pretty much an optimization technique.

Comment: @Laurent I think you are wrong. You would need a mighty big object, and no server side zipping of resources for it to be a useful optimization technique. I think a better design, and in fact the restful convention, is if you just wanted first name, you should specify that in the url string : "user/84/firstName/"

Comment: @NimChimpsky, in the end you can implement your service any way you want but there are certain benefits in following a RESTful approach. Probably you should read more about what these benefits are, then it would make more sense what a REST URL should look like.

Comment: @Laurent I am disagreeing with you what the restful convention is. You say use url parameters in get request is fine, I say no its not (as does this answer) - and it is not the restful approach.

Comment: "REST is an architecture" Wrong. It is an architectural style from which architectures are built. "and one of its demands is a clean URL (one that does not include params with a '?')" Wrong. Read http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm again and find that demand.

Comment: For every article you bring i can bring another that says you need clean URL's. But it doesn't really matter, it is derived for the definition of REST, you don't need someone to tell it specifically. Don't take my word for it, just look at ALL the new REST and MVC FW out there and show me one that doesn't use clean URL's.

Comment: @NimChimpsky - I agree with Laurent in that the answers don't contradict each other, though I would say Laurent's example for query params is a poor/unclear one. A better example would be `example.com/foo/?sort=first_name&asc=true`. In this instance, that snippet and `example.com/foo` would yield the same data, but the sorting would be done on the server (which is arguably better, because you can sort at the database level). The query string doesn't change the resource it's referencing, just the order it displays them.

Answer (score 5):

Here goes a third answer that contradicts the other two.

RESTful URI is almost an oxymoron. The semantics of the URI is irrelevant to REST, the only thing that matters to REST is that one URI identifies only one resource. Other than that, an URI is an atomic identifier, and its semantics are irrelevant.

For REST it doesn't matter if the URI pointing to a user resource for Joe Doe is:

```
http://example.com/users/joedoe
```

Or:

```
http://example.com/users?username=joedoe
```

Or:

```
http://example.com/jif892mfd02-18f2
```

Or even:

```
ftp://example.com/users/joedoe.json
```

It doesn't matter! URIs don't need to have any meaning in a RESTful application. People spend so much time designing meaningful URIs for their REST application, while they should be concerned with their media types. When you click a link on a webpage, you don't care about the semantics of the URI, you only care about the label. The same thing happens with a client using a REST API. The documentation of your media type should describe what links are available and what they do, through labels, and you simply follow them.

If you're concerned with the semantics of the URI, this is a sign that your clients are building URIs from some template in documentation, and you're not using HATEOAS, which means you're not doing REST at all.

Comment: But when you're a developer who has to integrate with that API and use it, it sure does help to have one that's well designed and follows existing conventions. Also, some people have to type a url manually sometimes, so having one that's easy to read can increase read or conversion rates. The ones without the ? and = are easier for humans, at least the average ones not the super-geniuses, to parse. :D

Comment: Nope. If you're a developer integrating with a RESTful API, you'll follow the URIs provided with the resources. If you do it right, you're likely to never need to deal directly with an URI other than storing it in a variable and then using the variable. If the service is asking for you to build URIs from templates given in documentation, then it isn't RESTful, simple as that.

Comment: Sure, this doesn't mean that you shouldn't give some thought to your URIs. It simply means that having URIs following convention X or Y don't make your API more or less RESTful. What makes your API RESTful is how you provide URIs to clients.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is if you're a developer integrating with RESTful service, it's more clear how things are structured if the urls follow a uniform interface or a pattern. For instance /users/employees/john tells us John is part of the employee collection, whereas /users/clients/beth tells us Beth is part of the client's collection. This is much more clear than /getClient?name=beth. Both tell you stuff. But the former tells you the full hierarchy visually.

Comment: That's wrong. The URI shouldn't tell you that john is an employee and beth is a client. Their media types should, and doesn't matter where they are. You could have /users/1 for john and /users/2 for beth, with john being returned with the media type for employee and beth for client. The server has complete control over the URI namespace and is free to change them at any time. If you're relying on the URI for that information, then your API is not RESTful.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say one is clearer than the other because you should be retrieving both by a link that references the user. When I click the link to your profile here, I don't care if it goes to /users/552972/jmort253 or /users/ajdh28746c or anything else. It can go to another site, and it doesn't matter. The only thing that matters is that it's the link StackOverflow is giving me to retrieve the profile of user jmort253. It only makes sense to say one is clearer than the other if you're not using HATEOAS, and therefore, not RESTful.

Comment: You're right that the link should be unique, but what I'm saying is that the pattern is there to make it easier for people to remember the structure when they need to do more advanced things than just click a link. In your example, the former is easier to remember than the latter.  It's all about whether you want to make it easier for people to remember the uri to retrieve a resource. When building an API, people aren't clicking links, they're making HTTP requests from those links, and if they're well designed, then it's self-documented.

Comment: Sorry, but you're saying the same thing and expecting a different answer. URIs are opaque to REST. It doesn't matter what's in them, if they are well designed, if they follow conventions or patterns. It doesn't matter. Period. If you're discussing this, then you don't really understand what REST is about. What you're saying is a genuine UI concern, and is valid, no doubt, but it has nothing to do with REST.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40441/discussion-between-jmort253-and-pedro-werneck)

Answer (score 3):

POST variables are definitely OK otherwise how would you submit a new resource or update it?

GET parameters are fine to specify how the resource should be rendered. So indeed `http://example.com/foo/?value=84` is not right - the URL doesn't represent a resource.

However, `http://example.com/user/84?fields=first_name,last_name` would be ok. In that case, you would use the additional query parameters to specify that you only want the first name and last name for that resource.

Comment: post variables : by specify the data in the url, I thought that was kinda the point to be honest.

Comment: @NimChimpsky think about the difference between data and presentation. A user list for example could be accessible through /users but then maybe you want to sort by last name /users?sort=lastname. It's still the same data, only presented slightly differently.

Comment: @ZetaTwo what on earth does rest specifically define then? It is just another name for using http requests to access and retrieve data as far as I can see. It suggests the convention of using delete and put for deleting and inserting data ? The other answer contradicts this one btw.

Comment: @NimChimpsky It's not just about the URLs. For a quick overview, read this section of the WP article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Constraints

Comment: @ZetaTwo yeah I'v read that and many others, its not clear to me and the other answer says it must be clean urls.

Comment: Huh? http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm says nothing about "GET parameters are fine to specify how the resource should be rendered". It *does* say that " any concept that might be the target of an author's hypertext reference must fit within the definition of a resource." At a high level, that means every URL you can legally construct is RESTful if it identifies a concept a client wants to identify.