# post json to spring mvc controller

Tags: java, javascript, json, spring, spring-mvc

Controller signature (I have tried as requestbody as well) :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Lame", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public
@ResponseBody
boolean getLame(@RequestParam String strToMatchA, @RequestParam String strToMatchB) {}
```

And this as my json :

```
{
"strToMatchA": "EN",
 "strToMatchB": "lon"
}
```

Not working, I receive the error :

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'strToMatchA' is not present
```

Removing this first parameter from method signature then makes it work (the method gets called correctly), what should I be doing ?

When I change method parameters to be annotated with `@RequestBody` I get the following error :

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

Comment: Did you compile with debugging enabled?  Otherwise, your parameter names will not be available.

Comment: @DavidGrant RequestParam will take parameter name defined in method signature. But I have tried whilst manually specify name too

Comment: Which library are you using for object-mapping? Is it Jackson or something else? Is it on the classpath? Additionally, the request method for RESTFul controllers should  basically be `GET` instead of `POST`.

Comment: @Lion jackson, it works for one paramter. Restful api should only use GET you say ? Debatable : http://stackoverflow.com/q/11522946/106261

Comment: so my json looks right to everyone ?

Comment: Is it a browser request? if so can you inspect the request using firebug?

Comment: @Lion only get?? Non sense, get is for retrieving data, not for pushing it. Post with json as body is the right way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your json is fine but not the controller signature. 
Create a class with setters matching the json.
Use it as argument instead of your strings. 
Annotate it with requestbody. It should work.

Comment: is there no other way ? I assumed spring coul dhandle multple request paramters ?

Comment: It can but its not a request parameter what you have is the body of the request

Comment: I have tried with both annoations. Neither is working. How can I do it using two method paramters ... ?

Comment: What are the both ways? I see only one. Check also that the content type is application/json. You cant, its not supposed toi work that way

Comment: Annoating method parameters with both requestparam, and requestbody ... OK, so I have to wrap in wrapper bject and change method signature.

Comment: Yes and put requestbody on the param

Comment: well I never, thanks. I always assumed you could pass multiple params.

Comment: I know it's a long time back, but I have come across a similar problem in spring boot, if you can help out, it would be great

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="auction/bids/add")
 public void addBid(@RequestBody Bid bid, @RequestParam("item_id") Integer item_id, @RequestParam("user_id") Integer user_id) {
  bidService.addBid(bid, item_id, user_id);
 }